# Set line character limit for emphasize-lines (code-block directive)

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

When I currently do this

```
.. code-block:: python
   :emphasize-lines: 3,5

   def some_function():
       interesting = False
       # 116 characters line
       print('This line is highlighted. but we exceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed line limit')
       print('This one is not...')
       print('...but this one is.')
```

It renders it like this, i.e the problem here is that it doesn't highlight the whole line (the line with the 116 characters).
[image]

The [docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-option-code-block-emphasize-lines) don't show how to set the line character limit for highlighting in the emphasize-line option. My question is how do I set line character limit for this option?

Sphinx version that I have:

```bash
$ sphinx-build --version
sphinx-build 4.5.0
```

Comment: The docs don't show it because it is not possible. You can however use a custom style to either crop it or wrap it.

Comment: @StevePiercy what custom style are you talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sphinx+custom+style